# Getting the id of an inserted entity in datomic?

Tags: clojure, datomic

After I run a transaction in datomic to insert a value, how I can use the return value of the transaction to get the ids of any entities that were created?

Here is a sample of the return value I get after an insert:

```
#<promise$settable_future$reify__4841@7c92b2e9: {:db-before datomic.db.Db@62d0401f, :db-after datomic.db.Db@bba61dfc,
 :tx-data [#Datum{:e 13194139534331 :a 50 
:v #inst "2013-06-19T11:38:08.025-00:00" 
:tx 13194139534331 :added true} #Datum{:e 17592186045436 .....
```

I can see the underlying datums...how can I extract their values?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [d/resolve-tempid](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/resolve-tempid). If you were to transact a single entity, looking at `:tx-data`  would work but if your transaction contained more than one entity, then you wouldn't know the order in which they appear in `:tx-data`.

What you should do is give temporary ids to your entities (before transacting them) using either `(d/tempid)` or its literal representation `#db/id[:db.part/user _negativeId_]` and then use `d/resolve-tempid` to go from your temporary id to the real id given by the database. The code would look something like:

```
(d/resolve-tempid (d/db conn) (:tempids tx) (d/tempid :db.part/user _negativeId_))
```

For a full **code sample**, see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/a2ndrade/5814355).

Comment: Ah sweet, I knew there should be an idiomatic way to do things. I was currently confining my approaches to functions that guaranteed they would only insert one entity, but it's really nice to be able to handle the general case.

Comment: Is `(d/transact conn [{:db/id "myentity" :some/attr 123}])` equivalent to `(d/tempid "myentity")`?

Comment: I have a situation where I need to know the entity id prior to insertion of the data, as I need to put that id somewhere else before I can get all the data necessary for insertion (Usually this is done via transaction in other databases). Would the tempid be useful for this. The fact that you can resolve a tempid to a real id seems to mean that I would later have to change the tempid to the real id.

Answer (score 7):

Ah, figured it out.

I had to deref the Clojure promise, and then I was able to yank out the values I wanted:

```
 (:e (second (:tx-data @(transact! conn query))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a quick function based on a2ndrade's answer. The naming isn't ideal and I may be committing idiomatic faux pas; suggestions are very much welcome.

```
(ns my.datomic.util
  (:require [datomic.api :as d]))

(defn transact-and-get-id
  "Transact tx and return entity id."
  [conn tx]
  (let [tempid (:db/id tx)
        post-tx @(d/transact conn [tx])
        db (:db-after post-tx)
        entid (d/resolve-tempid db (:tempids post-tx) tempid)]
    entid))
```

Example usage:

```
(def my-conn
  (d/connect (str "datomic:sql://datomic?jdbc:postgresql://"
                  "127.0.1:5432/datomic?user=datomic&password=somepw")

(defn thing-tx
  "Create transaction for new thing."
  [name]
  {:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user)
   :thing/name name})

(transact-and-get-id my-conn (thing-tx "Bob")) ;; => 17592186045502
```

Comment: looking good, man!  so am i right in reading that one would have to add the partition to the tx map? (to match with :db/id) ?

Comment: @sova Added an example. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

[The Tupelo Datomic library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/src/tupelo/datomic.adoc) has a function `(td/eids tx-result)` to easily extract the EIDs created in a transaction.  For example:

```
  ; Create Honey Rider and add her to the :people partition
  (let [tx-result   @(td/transact *conn* 
                        (td/new-entity :people ; <- partition is first arg (optional) to td/new-entity 
                          { :person/name "Honey Rider" :location "Caribbean" :weapon/type #{:weapon/knife} } ))
        [honey-eid]  (td/eids tx-result)  ; retrieve Honey Rider's EID from the seq (destructuring)
  ]
```