# What is the difference between the user-specified transaction temp-id and the one returned from a transaction, in Datomic?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I have the following clojure function which transacts to a Datomic database:

```
(defn demo-tran [term description]
(d/transact conn
          [{:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/utility -10034)
            :utility.tag/uuid (d/squuid)
            :utility.tag/term term
            :utility.tag/description description}]))
```

I then run this in the repl:

```
(demo-tran "Moo" "A bovine beast")
```

This succeeds and I am given back a 'transaction map':

```
{:db-before datomic.db.Db,
 @f4c9aa60 :db-after,
 datomic.db.Db @908ec69f,
 :tx-data [#datom[13194139534424 50 #inst"2016-04-01T09:16:50.945-00:00" 13194139534424 true]
       #datom[668503069688921 153 #uuid"56fe3c82-8dbd-4a0d-9f62-27b570cbb14c" 13194139534424 true]
       #datom[668503069688921 154 "Moo" 13194139534424 true]
       #datom[668503069688921 155 "A bovine beast" 13194139534424 true]],
 :tempids {-9222699135738586930 668503069688921}}
```

I have specified the tempid for this transaction as '-10034' so I would expect to find that negative number in the :tempids map. Instead I find -9222699135738586930. This is confusing. What is going on here?

I was hoping to be able to have the demo-tran function return the new EntityID but (other than guessing the position in the :tempids map) there is no way, given my inputs, to get to this value.

Comment: You might take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/17192764/597473.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one commenter mentions (via link), you need to use `resolve-tempid`, as documented [here](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/resolve-tempid) and demonstrated in the day of datomic project [here](https://github.com/Datomic/day-of-datomic/blob/98c1d9b2967ad5317e83b6da50f7c0e5c3d7a207/tutorial/component_attributes.clj#L28-L31).

In your case this would be something like:

```
(let [my-tempid (d/tempid :db.part/utility -100034)
      tx-result @(d/transact conn [{:db/id my-tempid
                                    :your "transaction"}])
      db-after (:db-after tx-result)
      tempids (:tempids tx-result)]
  (d/resolve-tempid db-after tempids my-tempid))
```